# OpenMP: How to use all available CPU to improve performance

Tags: c++, openmp, raspberry-pi3

**Platform:**
g++ on Raspberry Pi 3

**Library Used:**
OpenCV & OpenMP

**Question:**
I use openMP to improve performance for my tracking algorithm.
I have verified the code on Dual core NB and the Processing time become 50%.
then I porting the code on Raspberry Pi 3(four core)and the Processing time still become 50% compare to running on Raspberry Pi 3 without openMP.

**Expected Output:**
I expect it more faster~~~

**P.S**

1. without num_threads(4) I only output 0 and 1 by omp_get_thread_num()
2. omp_get_num_procs() >> I use this to make sure my core number is 4

**Critical Code**

```
vector<double> vSumRadio(sampleBoxNum, 0);
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (int j=0; j< sampleBoxNum; j++)
{
double eSumRadioTmp = 0;
        double eTmp1 = 0;
        double eTmp2 = 0;
        eSumRadioTmp = 0.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i<featureNum; i++)
        {
                double ePosTmp = 0, eNegTmp = 0;
                eTmp1 = (sampleValue[i][j]-Pos[i])*(sampleValue[i][j]-Pos[i]);
                eTmp2 = (sampleValue[i][j]-Neg[i])*(sampleValue[i][j]-Neg[i]);
                ePosTmp = exp(eTmp1/-(2.0f*sigmaPos[i]*sigmaPos[i]
                +1e-30))/(sigmaPos[i] + 1e-30);

                eNegTmp = exp(eTmp2/-(2.0f*sigmaNeg[i]*sigmaNeg[i]+
                1e-30))/(sigmaNeg[i]+1e-30);
                eSumRadioTmp += log(ePosTmp + 1e-30) - log(eNegTmp + 1e-30);
        }
        vSumRadio[j] = eSumRadioTmp;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are expecting a bit too much.  The processor clocks down from 1.2 GHz to 600 MHz if the power supply runs out of gas or the chip temperature gets too high.  Sample report is [available here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1320).

Comment: Performance is extremely sensitive to context, it would be good if you can provide more of that: A [mcve], absolute measured performance numbers, size of the involved data - even the type of `sampleValue` etc. is currently missing, compiler options. What Hans Passant said may certainly be the case here, so please take a look at the involved processor frequencies.

Comment: Strange. If without an explicit `num_threads()` clause you only get two threads, either the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable is set to `2` or the OS only sees two logical CPUs. Check `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev  I finally use top cmd to observed the CPU on Raspberry Pi 3. I find that I already use 4 core when I run my code. Maybe I really expect a bit too much.